# Is there a way to speed up this Fourier transform and optimise the results?

Tags: special-functions, fourier-analysis

Can anyone suggest a method of speeding up the evaluation of the following Fourier transform?

```
FourierTransform[UnitStep[t] Exp[-t/τ] Cos[(m t + ω0 ) t], t, ω]
```

I'm surprised by the amount of time this takes to evaluate, I have added in a linear chirp to the frequency so the variable $t$ in the argument of the $\cos$ now enters quadratically; so I suppose this is the culprit.

This takes quite some time to evaluate and when it does I am left with

```
    (1/(24 (m^2)^(7/4) Sqrt[
 2 π] τ^3))(6 m (m^2)^(
   3/4) τ^2 (I + τ ω - τ ω0) \
HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {3/4, 5/
     4}, -((I + τ ω - τ ω0)^4/(
     64 m^2 τ^4))] - 
  6 m (m^2)^(
   3/4) τ^2 (I + τ ω + τ ω0) \
HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {3/4, 5/
     4}, -((I + τ ω + τ ω0)^4/(
     64 m^2 τ^4))] + 
  I (m^2)^(3/
    4) (I + τ ω - τ ω0)^3 \
HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {5/4, 7/
     4}, -((I + τ ω - τ ω0)^4/(
     64 m^2 τ^4))] + 
  I (m^2)^(3/
    4) (I + τ ω + τ ω0)^3 \
HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {5/4, 7/
     4}, -((I + τ ω + τ ω0)^4/(
     64 m^2 τ^4))] + 
  3 (-I m^3 + (m^2)^(3/2)) Sqrt[
   2 π] τ^3 (Cos[(I + τ ω - τ ω0)^2/(
      4 m τ^2)] + 
     I Sin[(I + τ ω - τ ω0)^2/(
       4 m τ^2)]) + 
  3 (I m^3 + (m^2)^(3/2)) Sqrt[
   2 π] τ^3 (Cos[(I + τ ω + τ ω0)^2/(
      4 m τ^2)] - 
     I Sin[(I + τ ω + τ ω0)^2/(
       4 m τ^2)]))
```

This I wouldn't mind, but I don't know how to deal with the `HypergeometricPFQ` in the answers.

My goal is to eventually have a lovely peak-like lineshape at the end I can play with.

---

By adding some assumptions I can get something a little nicer

```
FT1 = FourierTransform[UnitStep[t] Exp[-t/τ] Cos[(m t + ω0 ) t], t, ω, Assumptions-> t > 0 && τ > 0 && ω > 0 && ω0 > 0]
```

However when I take the absolute value using `ComplexExpand[Abs[FT1]]`

I get a similarly as ugly

```
    √((-(((m^2)^(1/4)
        Cos[(-1 + (τ ω - τ ω0)^2)/(
        4 m τ^2)] Cos[
        1/2 Arg[I m]] Cosh[(τ ω - τ ω0)/(
        2 m τ^2)])/(2 Sqrt[2] m)) + ((m^2)^(1/4)
       Cos[(-1 + (τ ω + τ ω0)^2)/(
       4 m τ^2)] Cosh[(τ ω + τ ω0)/(
       2 m τ^2)])/(4 m) - (
     Cosh[(τ ω + τ ω0)/(
       2 m τ^2)] Sin[(-1 + (τ ω + τ \
ω0)^2)/(4 m τ^2)])/(
     4 (m^2)^(1/4)) + ((m^2)^(1/4)
       Cosh[(τ ω - τ ω0)/(
       2 m τ^2)] Sin[(-1 + (τ ω - τ \
ω0)^2)/(4 m τ^2)] Sin[1/2 Arg[I m]])/(
     2 Sqrt[2] m) + ((m^2)^(1/4)
       Cos[(-1 + (τ ω - τ ω0)^2)/(
       4 m τ^2)] Cos[
       1/2 Arg[I m]] Sinh[(τ ω - τ ω0)/(
       2 m τ^2)])/(
     2 Sqrt[2] m) - ((m^2)^(1/4)
       Sin[(-1 + (τ ω - τ ω0)^2)/(
       4 m τ^2)] Sin[
       1/2 Arg[I m]] Sinh[(τ ω - τ ω0)/(
       2 m τ^2)])/(
     2 Sqrt[2] m) + ((m^2)^(1/4)
       Cos[(-1 + (τ ω + τ ω0)^2)/(
       4 m τ^2)] Sinh[(τ ω + τ ω0)/(
       2 m τ^2)])/(4 m) - (
     Sin[(-1 + (τ ω + τ ω0)^2)/(
       4 m τ^2)] Sinh[(τ ω + τ ω0)/(
       2 m τ^2)])/(4 (m^2)^(1/4)))^2 + ((
     Cos[(-1 + (τ ω + τ ω0)^2)/(
       4 m τ^2)] Cosh[(τ ω + τ ω0)/(
       2 m τ^2)])/(
     4 (m^2)^(1/4)) + ((m^2)^(1/4)
       Cos[1/2 Arg[I m]] Cosh[(τ ω - τ ω0)/(
       2 m τ^2)] Sin[(-1 + (τ ω - τ \
ω0)^2)/(4 m τ^2)])/(
     2 Sqrt[2] m) + ((m^2)^(1/4)
       Cosh[(τ ω + τ ω0)/(
       2 m τ^2)] Sin[(-1 + (τ ω + τ \
ω0)^2)/(4 m τ^2)])/(
     4 m) + ((m^2)^(1/4)
       Cos[(-1 + (τ ω - τ ω0)^2)/(
       4 m τ^2)] Cosh[(τ ω - τ ω0)/(
       2 m τ^2)] Sin[1/2 Arg[I m]])/(
     2 Sqrt[2] m) - ((m^2)^(1/4)
       Cos[1/2 Arg[
         I m]] Sin[(-1 + (τ ω - τ ω0)^2)/(
       4 m τ^2)] Sinh[(τ ω - τ ω0)/(
       2 m τ^2)])/(
     2 Sqrt[2] m) - ((m^2)^(1/4)
       Cos[(-1 + (τ ω - τ ω0)^2)/(
       4 m τ^2)] Sin[
       1/2 Arg[I m]] Sinh[(τ ω - τ ω0)/(
       2 m τ^2)])/(2 Sqrt[2] m) + (
     Cos[(-1 + (τ ω + τ ω0)^2)/(
       4 m τ^2)] Sinh[(τ ω + τ ω0)/(
       2 m τ^2)])/(
     4 (m^2)^(1/4)) + ((m^2)^(1/4)
       Sin[(-1 + (τ ω + τ ω0)^2)/(
       4 m τ^2)] Sinh[(τ ω + τ ω0)/(
       2 m τ^2)])/(4 m))^2)
```

---

Seeing as I am posting a bounty on this question I think it is prudent to state what I am looking for. I am looking for a way to perform Fourier transforms of this form, what would be helpful is not only an answer to this problem, but also a more general guide when dealing with complicated time transients that one wants to transform. This is a damped wave with a linear frequency chirp, which is well [understood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp_spectrum#Linear_chirp).

I'd like to be able to figure out how I can get Mathematica to perform such computations so I can play around a look at my resultant line-shapes.

Comment: I've added some additional working to help constrain the problem.

Comment: For $m=1$ Maple 2019.1 performs a simpler result in terms of the erf function.

Comment: @user64494 thanks. Unfortunately I don't have Maple!

Comment: May present the Maple result through Dropbox on demand.

Comment: @user64494 if you can show the result with the variable $m$ as a free parameter that would be great!

Comment: Here https://www.dropbox.com/s/8m89hyzmf05uddg/FT.pdf?dl=0 it is. It should be noticed that the definition of Fourier transform in Maple (see https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=examples/fourier ) differs from the  Mathematica one by a constant multiplier.

Comment: @Thanks!! That is at least something to play with!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The explicit integral doesn't take long and is quite simple (compared to what you have):

```
Assuming[τ > 0 && m > 0 && Element[ω0, Reals] && Element[ω, Reals],
  1/Sqrt[2 π] Integrate[Exp[-t/τ] Cos[(m t + ω0) t] E^(I ω t),
  {t, 0, ∞}] // FullSimplify]
```

> $$
> \frac{(-1)^{1/4} \left(e^{\frac{2 \tau  \omega +i}{2 m \tau ^2}} \left(1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{(-1)^{3/4} (\tau  (\omega +\omega_0)+i)}{2 \sqrt{m} \tau }\right)\right)-i e^{\frac{i
>    \left(\omega ^2+\omega_0^2\right)}{2 m}} \left(1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{(-1)^{1/4} (\tau  (\omega -\omega_0)+i)}{2 \sqrt{m} \tau }\right)\right)\right) \exp \left(-\frac{i \tau ^2
>    (\omega +\omega_0)^2+2 \tau  (\omega -\omega_0)+i}{4 m \tau ^2}\right)}{4 \sqrt{2m}}
> $$

In case it's not correct to assume $m>0$ as I did, then you can replace that assumption by $m\in\mathbb{R}$ and get a slightly different answer.

Make a plot:

```
With[{ω0 = 1, τ = 100, m = 0.001},
  Plot[Abs[((-1)^(1/4) E^(-((I + 2 τ (ω - ω0) + I τ^2 (ω + ω0)^2)/(4 m τ^2))) (-I E^((I (ω^2 + ω0^2))/(2 m)) (1 + Erf[((-1)^(1/4) (I + τ (ω - ω0)))/(2 Sqrt[m] τ)]) + E^((I + 2 τ ω)/(2 m τ^2)) (1 + Erf[((-1)^(3/4) (I + τ (ω + ω0)))/(2 Sqrt[m] τ)])))/(4 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[m])]^2,
    {ω, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

Comment: really thanks a lot for this. One additional question, if I further complicate this integral by adding say a Hanning Window, do you have any hint as to how to make this execute more efficiently? I'm playing with your example and adding `HannWindow[t]` significantly increases computation time. At the time of writng it is still running...

Comment: Usually you would *convolve* with a window function, which would be a multiplication in Fourier space: just multiply the already found Fourier transform with the [Fourier transform of the Hann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hann_function#Fourier_transform). Or did I misunderstand and you want to use the Hann function in time instead of the `UnitStep[t]` factor in the original problem?

Comment: For a Hann window of duration $\tau$, maybe this could work: `Assuming[τ > 0 && m > 0 && ω0 > 0, 1/Sqrt[2 π] Integrate[Sin[(π t)/τ]^2 Cos[(m t + ω0) t] E^(I ω t), {t, 0, τ}]]`. Maybe add a `FullSimplify` inside the `Assuming` if you can bear the slowness.

Comment: I'm trying to get a line shape analytically, that resembles the FFT of some data. And as I understand it the windows should always be multiplied in, in the time domain. So yeah a straight swap of UnitStep. I only ever add unit step, as I usually use FourierTransform rather than the direct integration, as without UnitStep FourierTransform returns strange results even for simple transforms.

Answer (score 0):

What version of *Mathematica* were you using?  Using MMA Version 11.2.0 for Linux I get, using

```
 ft=FourierTransform[UnitStep[t] Exp[-t/\[Tau]] Cos[(m t + \[Omega]0) t], t, \[Omega]] ,
```

the result

```
 (((1 + I*Erfi[(I + \[Tau]*\[Omega] - \[Tau]*\[Omega]0)/(2*Sqrt[I*m]*\[Tau])])*(Cos[(I + \[Tau]*\[Omega] - \[Tau]*\[Omega]0)^2/(4*m*\[Tau]^2)] + I*Sin[(I + \[Tau]*\[Omega] - \[Tau]*\[Omega]0)^2/(4*m*\[Tau]^2)]))/Sqrt[I*m] + ((1 + Erf[(m*(I + \[Tau]*\[Omega] + \[Tau]*\[Omega]0))/(2*((-I)*m)^(3/2)*\[Tau])])*(Cos[(I + \[Tau]*\[Omega] + \[Tau]*\[Omega]0)^2/(4*m*\[Tau]^2)] - I*Sin[(I + \[Tau]*\[Omega] + \[Tau]*\[Omega]0)^2/(4*m*\[Tau]^2)]))/Sqrt[(-I)*m])/(4*Sqrt[2])
```

which, displayed in `TeXForm`, is
$\frac{\frac{\left(1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{m (\tau  \omega +\tau  \text{$\omega $0}+i)}{2 (-i m)^{3/2} \tau }\right)\right) \left(\cos \left(\frac{(\tau 
   \omega +\tau  \text{$\omega $0}+i)^2}{4 m \tau ^2}\right)-i \sin \left(\frac{(\tau  \omega +\tau  \text{$\omega $0}+i)^2}{4 m \tau
   ^2}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{-i m}}+\frac{\left(1+i \text{erfi}\left(\frac{\tau  \omega -\tau  \text{$\omega $0}+i}{2 \sqrt{i m} \tau }\right)\right)
   \left(i \sin \left(\frac{(\tau  \omega -\tau  \text{$\omega $0}+i)^2}{4 m \tau ^2}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{(\tau  \omega -\tau  \text{$\omega
   $0}+i)^2}{4 m \tau ^2}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{i m}}}{4 \sqrt{2}}$.

I'm not sure what a sensible range of parameters is, but I tried a plotting a few cases, e.g., `Plot[Abs[ft/.{m->2,\[Tau]->4/3,\[Omega]0->1/5}],{\[Omega],-20,20}`], and obtained, I guess, plausible looking results.  (But forgot how to
include graphics here.)

Comment: Interesting, I'm using Mathematica 11.0....Perhaps time for an upgrade!

Comment: Can't reproduce it in version 12.0 on Windows 10 32-bit. I obtain the same result as in the question.

Comment: @user64494 Does it agree with your Maple results?  Now, I don’t have Maple, nor have I installed MMA version 12.

Comment: @QuantumPenguin if you only care about additional stuff like this, the online version of Mathematica (in the Wolfram Cloud) can do stuff like this and doesn't cost you anything more.

Answer (score 0):

Using MMA Version 12.0 for Windows I get:

```
FT1 = Assuming[{m > 0, τ > 0, ω0 > 0}, FourierTransform[
UnitStep[t] Exp[-t/τ] Cos[(m t + ω0) t], t, ω]] // FullSimplify;
ComplexExpand[Abs[FT1], TargetFunctions -> {Abs, Arg}] // FullSimplify

(* ((E^((2 (ω + ω0))/(m τ)))^(1/4)
Abs[1 + Erf[((-1)^(3/4) (I + τ (ω + ω0)))/(
2 Sqrt[m] τ)] - 
I E^((I ((I + τ ω)^2/τ^2 + ω0^2))/(2 m))
 Erfc[-(((-1)^(1/4) (I + τ (ω - ω0)))/(
  2 Sqrt[m] τ))]])/(4 Sqrt[2] (m^2)^(1/4)) *)
```

which, displayed in TeXForm, is:

$$\frac{\sqrt[4]{e^{\frac{2 (\omega +\text{$\omega $0})}{m \tau }}} \left|\text{erf}\left(\frac{(-1)^{3/4} (\tau  (\omega +\text{$\omega $0})+i)}{2 \sqrt{m} \tau }\right)-i
   e^{\frac{i \left(\frac{(\tau  \omega +i)^2}{\tau ^2}+\text{$\omega $0}^2\right)}{2 m}} \text{erfc}\left(-\frac{\sqrt[4]{-1} (\tau  (\omega -\text{$\omega $0})+i)}{2 \sqrt{m}
   \tau }\right)+1\right|}{4 \sqrt{2} \sqrt[4]{m^2}}$$